# Modify existing regex to only match dates with a year between 1900-2100

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, date

I have dates formatted in the following format: `2008-01-01`

My current regex (.NET) is: `^((((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})-(0[13578]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})-(0[13456789]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30))|(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})-02-(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))|(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))-02-29))$`

And it handles the dates just fine. However, how do I change the regex to only match with dates with years in between the year 1900 and 2100?

Comment: Any reason you need to do this in a regexp? It would be much easier to parse the date and simply check the year value.

Comment: @Kenney Unfortunately the change would be system wide, and with the existing architecture it would make the most sense to adjust the regex at this point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following one:

```
^((((19\d{2})|(20\d{2})|2100)-(0[13578]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|
(((19\d{2})|(20\d{2})|2100)-(0[13456789]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30))|
(((19\d{2})|(20\d{2})|2100)-02-(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))|(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|
[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))-02-29))$
```

You can see it working [here](http://pei.to/cqvw).

Comment: @errorreplicating Have you tried what I wrote?